# autonomous map building with turtlebot 2?

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there.  we're trying to build an "autonomous map building" feature for turtlebot 2.  for example, we want to place turtlebot 2 in a room and it will automatically go around the room to build the room map (without us sending teleop commands).

we tried to use a couple of existing packages like /explore, but it's been hit and miss.  sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work (i.e. doesn't capture the entire room floor plan).

what is your recommendation for building this?

dh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187944/autonomous-map-building-with-turtlebot-2?/) by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-07-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We did something similar with Pioneer robots. The software included autonomous exploration and mapping and is now available for Hydro and Indigo: http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d

Maybe you can also use it on a Turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-28**:
what is your experience with the exploration package?  we tried it already, but it's hit and miss.  it didn't capture 100% of the floor plan.  we had to manually drive it (via teleop) to certain areas of the rooms that it couldn't reach.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2014-07-28**:
Well, I made it, so it used to work nicely! ;)
We used it both indoor and outdoor, but it's primarily for indoor use. What did the map look like when the exploration finished? Have you checked if it aborted or finished the exploration?

**Comment by [hasnain](https://answers.ros.org/users/33864/hasnain/) on 2018-03-26**:
Hi, how did you use the nav2d package? Can you please share some sort of guides/instructions. I am really stuck

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-01-17**:
How do I use nav2D package with a swarm of 4 [hector quadrotors](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) to map an unknown environment autonomously? @[Sebastian Kaperski]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The frontier exploration module (http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration) is built as a plugin to the basic ros navigation stack, and works with gmapping to explore an unknown area. See the launch files for usecases.

If you're having reliability/repeatability issues, try testing the exploration algorithm in gazebo first, to determine whether the error source is high or low level. It could be anything from the exploration planner, to your navigation stack setup, to issues with your sensor setup.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hasnain](https://answers.ros.org/users/33864/hasnain/) on 2018-03-26**:
Hi, we are working on a similar problem. We have installed the frontier_exploration package but it requires manual instructions in terms of where do u want the robot to go (polygons). How do we modify/do what needs to be done in order for the robot to move on its own i.e. without external commands.